# Can I reduce download and/or storage size in Firebase realtime database by using int instead of string?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create customer accounts and store phone numbers in Firebase realtime database. So, if I store the phone number as an integer instead of string, does it reduce the download/storage size of the data? I found in the Firestore documentation that this is indeed the case, though I'm not sure whether it is similar for Realtime DB too.

Answer (score 1):

It will reduce the size by a **very** small amount, just a few bytes.  Probably not enough to notice.  It's not an optimization I would **not** recommend.

Also, you probably don't want to store a phone number as a number type.  Best practice is to only use number types for data that you intend to do math on.  Phone numbers don't participate in math.  They are really just strings that are made up of mostly numbers, sometimes "+" for country codes, and sometimes other characters for organization.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for replying. So, when you say a few bytes, is that exactly equal to the difference in size between the String and int data type? For example, a phone number of length 10 will have a size of 8 bytes when stored as an int, and a size of 10 when stored as a String right?

Comment: I don't know how long the phone numbers are that you intend to store.  Each nation has different numbering schemes.  But yes, you will have to consider the difference between whatever you want to store as a string compared to the size of a number.